# Cannot scroll with mobile view of website

Tags: css, mobile

I am unable to scroll down on my website.  By deleting various files to test, I know it exists somewhere in my css file.  I tried different variations of the overflow command (based on similar questions here on stackflow first) to no avail.
I deleted the various javascript links in the header as a test, but the scrolling problem remains.

I will edit my question with more information if I did not give you the required info.  Thank you so much.

```
body {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2;
    overflow:hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#00293C;
}

h2 {
    color: #a0a0a0;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
p {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

a:link {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: #666666;
}
a:hover{
    color: #666666;
}
a:active{
    color: #666666;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.2em !important;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #a0a0a0;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

ul li:first-child a {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
ul li:last-child a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
ul li a:active,ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #01538B;
    color: white;
} 

li{
    min-height:60px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #eaeaea;
}
li:last-child { border-bottom: none;  } 
li a{
    display:block;
    min-height:60px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    background-size:19px 14px;
    background-image: url(../img/list-arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 29px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#header {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#00293C;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 80px;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    color: #005F9B;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
#return_header {
    /*position:fixed;*/
    /*margin-top: -100px;*/
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#333333;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 10px;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #005F9B;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#content {
  /*margin-top: 100px;*/
}
#header img {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #82ba31 inset, 0px 0px 0px 1px #e6e6e6;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
#bottom {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#00293C;
    min-height: 8px;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
}  
#footer {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
} 
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    background: #005F9B;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #82ba31 inset, 0px 0px 0px 4px #e6e6e6;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #82ba31 inset, 0px 0px 0px 4px #e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #82ba31 inset, 0px 0px 0px 4px #e6e6e6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #497a03;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    border-color: #00487B;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
      
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   WebFontConfig = {
     google: { families: [ 'Source+Sans+Pro::latin', 'Ropa+Sans::latin', 'Open+Sans::latin' ] }
   };
   (function() {
     var wf = document.createElement('script');
     wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
       '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
     wf.type = 'text/javascript';
     wf.async = 'true';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
   })(); 
</script>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $( "body" ).hide().fadeIn(800);
  $( "#header" ).hide().fadeIn(1200);
});
</script>
        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> </head>
<body>
```

You can see the website here (apologize for the login requirement I made a temp login):
if you go to edoclist.com/mobile

username and password is both test123@test123.com

a

Comment: Definitely need to post your HTML too. Create a snippet so people can open this on their phones and see if they can replicate the problem.

Comment: It's better if you could provide JS Fiddle so we can see what's your actual problem?

Comment: I edited above with the website itself because i couldnt get the html code past the error check here on stackoverflow.  I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Your `body` has an overflow of `hidden`. Unless there is any container inside the body that is scrollable (`overflow: scroll`) or similar, then your page won't scroll.

Comment: I tried overflow:scoll; in the body and it still did not scroll.  I notice I have overflow:hidden in other parts of the css (like under #header, #footer etc).  I am not sure whether I also have to convert all those to "scroll".  I did not try that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `overflow:hidden`, do `overflow-x:hidden`.

Comment: didn't work.  I also deleted overflow:hidden from the #header line.  Not sure why it is there and in the Body container....